# manytomany relation - django

Tags: python, django

I have models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField()
  content = models.TextField()

class Newspaper(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField()
  content = models.TextField()

class Author(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name="person_as_author")
  book = models.ManyToManyField(Book,related_name="book_authors",null=True, blank=True, default=None)
  newspaper = models.ManyToManyField(Newspaper,related_name="newspaper_authors",null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

There is Person `Adam`. Now I need all books, where adam is author.

I tried this:

```
#person is Adam
books = []
person_as_authors = person.person_as_author.all()
for each in person_as_authors: 
   books.append(each.book.get())
```

but it is saying

```
Book matching query does not exist.
```

because that instance's `book` is None. That instance has `newspaper`.

How can I here filter and get only books into `books` list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Book.objects.filter(book_authors__person=adam).distinct()
```

In general, if `Books` are what you want to end up with, you probably want to start your query with `Book.objects.filter()`. Sometimes you can just use a related manager (`author.books.filter()`), and sometimes you might need to loop as you did (or use raw SQL), but in general I find it helpful to think about it from the result backwards: "What I need are `Books`, where this and this and this are true..."

Comment: thanks, working like a charm. how can I count the number of books from ``person`` model's side?

Comment: @doniyor: To get the count you can just put `.count()` on the end. I'm not sure what you mean by *from `person` model's side*? This *is* how you get the `Books` given a `person`.

Comment: i am in template with person instance. i cannot do this query in template, i tried ``person.person_as_author__book.count`` in template, but it is giving me nothing

Comment: @doniyor: Ah, I see. No, you can't do this kind of filtering in the template. I would recommend putting this query in a method on `Person` (something like `get_books`). Then you can call it from your `person` object in the template.